# SCSS/SASS no mapping/compiling into CSS

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, adobe-brackets

I'm quite a fresh Sass user and I'm trying to get off the ground using it. I like the SMACSS hierarchy and have tried to incorporate that into my project as you see in the image here, ***using Brackets***:

[image: SMACSS Sass Snippet Overview]

It compiles via Ruby installed on my pc. However, no matter what I do, the main.scss file isn't mapped and doesn't translate into the main.css file. The only thing in the main.css file is

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map*/
```

I've searched the web and haven't found an answer. Any Sass users out there with some advice?

What's interesting is when I made a "robotodraft.scss" file directly in the vendor directory folder, as shown in this link [FontFaceKit RobotoDraft](https://github.com/FontFaceKit/robotodraft), it works! A css and css.map file are automatically generated with the content!

However when I try the same with _underscorefiles in multiple folders linking to a main css in the styles folder as you see in the above image, I get nothing.

My vendor folder looks like this

[image]

**UPDATE** *6/25/16*

I made a font.scss file to point to the folder and files containing my fonts I want to use and it compiled! I still can't figure out why my main.scss can't compile. There are no syntax errors in the file. *See font file below*

[image]

Comment: Do you actually have a file `main.css.map` in the same directory as the `main.css` file?

Comment: Yes, as shown in the picture. It's within the "styles" folder.

Comment: You really need to explain how you are compiling your SCSS. And if you're not sure, you probably aren't. Please confirm how you are exactly compiling your SCSS. Then we can move on with troubleshooting

Comment: It's auto-compiling via Ruby installed on my Windows 10. Just in case the answer includes Compass, I've installed that also using the Ruby cmd prompt.

Comment: From what I understand, you're trying to say that your sass doesn't build properly. We know it hasn't built properly when you get no css files generated, but, we should also know what the compiler tells us in order to troubleshoot. It's impossible to help you without some error output. Too many files and a sketchy description of the problem and what you're doing to recreate it. Check in your command line to see if you're getting any errors back. Or you're going to need to edit your question to demonstrate the problem in more clarity

Comment: @Jonathan Thing is, I can't find an empty sass project example similar to my setup to base it off of. Additionally I tried troubleshooting via Ruby's command prompt but I'm not sure how to create a log through that method, nor can I find that information through google searches. I feel like an idiot, that the information should be out there, but I'm just not coming across it. The only thing I can go off of is my success when creating a non underscore file to group the underscored files in the same directory. No success outside of directory. Maybe more pictures to would help?

Answer (score 2):

Usually, when SASS doesn't compile, it means that there is a syntax error somewhere. I'm unfamiliar with what editor you are using or how your SASS is precompiling, but check for errors in your console or in your individual files.

There is a link to "styles/typography.css" in line 17 of index.html, which I don't see in your folder structure anywhere. Again, depending on how you're compiling, this may or may not be the problem.

If you are calling "typography" via @import somewhere in your partials, that would definitely halt compilation and prevent a compilation of main.css

Comment: Right! I had a feeling it may be a syntax error problem, however, no matter what I did, I get nothing. 

What's interesting is when I made a "robotodraft.scss" file directly in the vendor directory folder, as shown in this link [link](https://github.com/FontFaceKit/robotodraft), it works! A css and css.map file are automatically generated with the content!

However when I try the same with _underscorefiles in multiple folders linking to a main css in the styles folder. I get nothing. I'll update the original post for clarity.

Comment: Could be an issue with the partials themselves. Since I can't see those contents, I can't tell you -- but you could try commenting out each partial in main.scss (all at first, and prove a successful compilation) then one by one, uncomment them back in. When it breaks you know which file the problem is in. Your main.scss file should work just like you did your fonts.scss file. It looks good to me, which leads me to believe the problem is in one of the partials. Happy hunting!

Answer (score 2):

You're using an underscore (`_`) as a file prefix, which is reserved for partial `sass` (like `require` in Ruby, or `include` in C)...

Make sure you either drop the underscore or use an `import` directive correctly (maybe it was `include` directive, I can't remember of the top of my head).

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer from this [method](https://github.com/minamarkham/sassy-starter), which is basically like placing an ambassador file for each subfolder you use in your Sass-based project. I used an index.scss file in each folder that referenced to all files in each folder, then I simply imported those index files in my main.scss using the proper @import syntax. I'm not exactly sure what was causing it to not compile before, but safe to say it's best to keep it simple and clean with Sass architecture.